# empty byte array c# winrt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have `WriteableBitmap`. I know that in variable `wp1` exists image, because I saved this picture, and it was all fine. I need to encode the image into a `byte[]` array.

```
WriteableBitmap wp1 = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1); ;
wp1.SetSourceAsync(memStream);

using (Stream stream = wp1.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    if (stream.CanWrite)
    {
        byte[] pixelArray = new byte[stream.Length];
        await stream.ReadAsync(pixelArray, 0, pixelArray.Length);
    }
}
```

After all the `pixelArray` is empty. Length of the array `pixelArray` equals to the length of `stream`, but all bytes are zero. What should I do?

Comment: Why are you checking for the ability to *write* to the stream before *reading* from it? It's not really clear what you're trying to do here. I strongly suspect that `SetSourceAsync` isn't what you want - and I notice you're not awaiting it, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is this line of code:

```
wp1.SetSourceAsync(memStream);
```

That's an asynchronous method, so you'll have to wait until it's done before proceeding. Try changing it to:

```
await wp1.SetSourceAsync(memStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WriteableBitmap Extensions, there's an easier method that does that for you, something like :`var pixelDataArray = wp1.ToByteArray();`